# How to validate interdependent numeric fields using Yup?

Tags: typescript, formik, yup

I have a model with interdependent numeric fields and I'm struggling to see how to setup a complex validation using [yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup).

For the sake of simplicity, imagine an object having the following shape:

```
{
    a: number,
    b: number
}
```

I would like to validate that `b` is less then half of `a`.

So conceptually what I would want is something like this:

```
yup.object().shape({
    a: yup
        .number(),
    b: yup
        .number()
        .max(a/2) <-- DOES NOT WORK
```

Of course, this does not work since there is no `a` in scope there.

Using `test`, I don't see how to get the whole object into scope:

```
yup.object().shape({
    a: yup
        .number(),
    b: yup
        .number()
        .test('test', 'b should be less than a/2', b => b < a/2) <-- DOES NOT WORK
```

And using `when` (conditional validation) also doesn't seem to help although it seems to be used for complex validation of interdependent fields:

```
yup.object().shape({
    a: yup
        .number(),
    b: yup
        .number()
        .when('a', {is: true, then: yup.number().max(a/2)}) <-- DOES NOT WORK
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that there are other overloads of [`when`](https://github.com/jquense/yup#mixedwhenkeys-string--arraystring-builder-object--value-schema-schema-schema) that pass on the value of the tested field:

```
yup.object().shape({
a: yup
    .number(),
b: yup
    .number()
    .when('a', (a, schema) => return schema.max(a/2))
```